# Explainable anomaly detection

Tags: anomaly-detection, outlier, explainable-ai

There are plenty of working for explaining prediction in supervised learning (e.g. SHAP values, LIME).

What about for anomaly detection in unsupervised learning? Is there any model for which there are libraries that can give you justifications, such as "row x is an anomaly because feature 1 is higher than 5.3 and feature 5 is equal to 'No'"?

Comment: SHAP values and the shap Python library can be used, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620108/finding-source-of-cause-in-anomaly-detection).

Answer (score 2):

The LIME framework can probably be used to do this as well.

Outlier detection sets a specific label to outliers (say 1), and another one to inliers (say 0). From then on, you can train interpretable models (decision trees for instance) to predict the labels set by your unsupervised model.

I don't know much about SHAP values, but I guess, with this approach, you could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SHAP Kernal Explainer for unsupervised model but you should get sth as output. you might need to create a pipeline so that you just pass pipeline variable to shap kernal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [outliertree](https://github.com/david-cortes/outliertree) which is doing exactly that. It uses decision trees to provide human readable explanations of outliers/anomalies.

Also see the related paper [Explainable outlier detection through decision tree conditioning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00636).

Answer (score 0):

please check the latest survey on Explainable Anomaly Detection(July 2023) via [A Survey on Explainable Anomaly Detection](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3609333)

Comment: only url answer